# List items dots (<ul>) and numbers(<o>) not showing and unable to remove (overflow-x: hidden) from my root in CSS

Tags: html, css, list, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a web page and I have encountered an issue with my list items. The dots and numbers that usually appear next to each list item are not showing up. Additionally, when i remove the overflow-x: hidden; property in my CSS the list items numbers and dots show immediately, the texts are showing all the time though.

```
**THIS IS THE HTML**

  <body>
   

        <main>
          <section>
           
              <div>
                <h2 id="getting-started" class="heading-color mt-5">
                  GETTING STARTED
                </h2>
                <p>
                  There are 2 ways to join Fyre Skin Brand Partnership Program.
                </p>
                <ol>
                  <li>
                    Join directly from the Fyre Skin website by clicking the
                    link.
                    <a href="https://brandpartner.fyreskin.com.ng/register"
                      >Register</a
                    >
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Join using the link of a brand partner that recommended you
                    and they automatically become you Up-line partner and you
                    their Down-line partner.
                  </li>
                </ol>
                <p>
                  If you decide to join, the startup registration is 25,000
                  Naira with a monthly renewal of 10,000 Naira.
                </p>
                <p>Your monthly subscription gives you access to</p>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    Your own back office dashboard were you can see your
                    commission, payments, pending payments, bonuses, sales made
                    using your link, clients who bought using your link, team
                    members profile, team members sales and profit and marketing
                    tools .
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Your own personalise Fyre Skin website that your potential
                    clients can shop with.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Your personalised brand partnership link for potential
                    clients .
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Your personalised Networking link for building your own
                    team.
                  </li>
                  <li>Growth and development training for personal growth.</li>
                  <li>A community of entrepreneurs that you can learn from.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                  <span class="fw-bold">How to get started - </span>For us at
                  Fyre Skin convenience is everything that why we built a
                  website that’s swift and easy to access by both brand partners
                  and clients.
                </p>
                <ol>
                  <li>
                    After signing up and creating an account, login into your
                    back office the click copy
                    <span class="fw-bold">‘default brand partners link’</span>.
                    Share your link on
                    <span class="fw-bold">social platforms</span> that can be
                    visible potential clients.
                  </li>
                  <img src="" />
                 
                <div>
                  <ol>
                    <li>Create a target audience</li>
                    <li>
                      Set a daily goal target that includes number of people and
                      how much he want to make.
                    </li>
                    <li>Set the amount of times he want to work a week.</li>
                    <li>Products and services he want to market (optional)</li>
                  </ol>
                </div>
                <p>Target: 40% male, 60% female</p>
                <p>Goals: 4 people a day, ₦50,000 a day</p>
                <p>Work: 4 times a week</p>
                <p>
                  <span>
                    *lets assume Ade already did his homework by attending our
                    webinars, where he learnt how to market like a pro and he
                    already posted his business links on every social platform
                    and uses his online messaging apps.
                  </span>
                </p>
                <div>
                  <div class="heading-color mt-5">
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 1</h5>
                  </div>
                  <p>
                    Ade’s target for the day is 4 people and he got 2 men and 2
                    women.
                  </p>
                  <p><span>MEN</span></p>
                  <p>1st man did deep tissue massage and jelly pedicure</p>
                  <p>
                    2nd man never left his house, he just order online 1 ultra
                    shade Creamy gel and 1 Lightening glow milk
                  </p>
                  <p><span>WOMEN</span></p>
                  <p>
                    1st woman did a brightening facials and braided her hair
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    2nd woman did a botanical pedicure and botanical manicure
                  </p>
                  <div>
                    <table
                      class="table table-responsive table-bordered border-dark"
                    >
                      <tr class="th">
                        <th>MEN</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                        <th>WOMEN</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Deep Tissues massage</td>
                        <td>12,000</td>
                        <td>Brightening facials</td>
                        <td>9,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Jelly Pedicure</td>
                        <td>5,000</td>
                        <td>Corn row</td>
                        <td>5,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Ultra shade creamy gel</td>
                        <td>5,000</td>
                        <td>Botanical pedicure</td>
                        <td>5,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Lightening glow milk</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>Botanical manicure</td>
                        <td>3,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>TOTAL</td>
                        <td>32,000</td>
                        <td>TOTAL</td>
                        <td>22,000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
              <div class="heading-color "><h5 class="total">OVERALL TOTAL =54,000</h5></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
                  <div class="heading-color mt-5">
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 2</h5>
                  </div>
                  <p>Ade repeated same target as day 1.</p>
                  <p>
                    4 people but this time his message only attracted 4 women
                    who just wanted to do the best friends package and relax
                    themselves.
                  </p>
                  <p><span>WOMEN</span></p>
                  <p>2 best-friends package comprises of 3 services each -</p>
                  <p>
                    deep cleansing facials, Swedish massage and botanical
                    pedicure
                  </p>
                  <div>
                    <table
                      class="table table-responsive table-bordered border-dark"
                    >
                      <tr class="th">
                        <th>WOMEN</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Best friend package</td>
                        <td>42,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Best friend package</td>
                        <td>42,000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="heading-color">
                      <h5 class="total"  >OVERALL TOTAL =84,000</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="heading-color mt-5">
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 3</h5>
                  </div>
                  <p>
                    Same target, same goal. 4 people. Repeated strategy brings
                    repeated results
                  </p>
              
  </body>
</html>
```

```
MY CSS
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap'); 

  /* Custom color variables */
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
   
  }
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
:root {
  --primary: #e67e22;
  --secondary: #16a085;
  --success: #2ecc71;
  --danger: #e74c3c;
  --warning: #F0FF42;
  --info: #3498db;
  --light: #f5f5f5;
  --dark: #2c3e50;
 
}

.container
{
  font-weight: 400;


}

img{
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
a{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
p{
  text-align: left;
}
button {
  height: 50px;

  
}
.header{
  margin-left: 50px;
 
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
.heading-color{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
span{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.th{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
li{
  font-weight: 600;
}
td{
  font-weight: 600;}

.total{
  text-align: center;
}

  @media (max-width : 450px){
  .container{
    width: 375px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }
  
}
```

I have tried several solutions such as using different CSS selectors to target the list items, and also tried to override the overflow-x property with overflow-x: visible; but it gives me an overflow on my webpage. I have also checked for any other conflicting CSS styles that may be causing the issue, but I have not found any.

Answer (score 0):

The list items' numbers and dots are showing in my snippet.

Try this:

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');  
  /* Custom color variables */
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;       
  }
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
:root {
  --primary: #e67e22;
  --secondary: #16a085;
  --success: #2ecc71;
  --danger: #e74c3c;
  --warning: #F0FF42;
  --info: #3498db;
  --light: #f5f5f5;
  --dark: #2c3e50;
}   
.container
{
  font-weight: 400;        
}    
img{
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
a{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
p{
  text-align: left;
}
button {
  height: 50px;          
}
.header{
  margin-left: 50px;     
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
.heading-color{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
span{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.th{
  background-color: #F0FF42;
}
li{
  font-weight: 600;
}
td{
  font-weight: 600;
}    
.total{
  text-align: center;
}    
  @media (max-width : 450px){
  .container{
    width: 375px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }      
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>   
    <main>
      <section>
        <div>
          <h2 id="getting-started" class="heading-color mt-5">GETTING STARTED</h2>
          <p>There are 2 ways to join Fyre Skin Brand Partnership Program.</p>
          <ol>
            <li>Join directly from the Fyre Skin website by clicking the link.
              <a href="https://brandpartner.fyreskin.com.ng/register">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li>Join using the link of a brand partner that recommended you and they automatically become you Up-line partner and you their Down-line partner.
            </li>
          </ol>
          <p>If you decide to join, the startup registration is 25,000 Naira with a monthly renewal of 10,000 Naira.</p>
          <p>Your monthly subscription gives you access to</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Your own back office dashboard were you can see your commission, payments, pending payments, bonuses, sales made using your link, clients who bought using your link, team members profile, team members sales and profit and marketing tools.</li>
            <li>Your own personalise Fyre Skin website that your potential clients can shop with.</li>
            <li>Your personalised brand partnership link for potential clients.</li>
            <li>Your personalised Networking link for building your own team.</li>
            <li>Growth and development training for personal growth.</li>
            <li>A community of entrepreneurs that you can learn from.</li>
          </ul>
          <p><span class="fw-bold">How to get started - </span>For us at Fyre Skin convenience is everything that why we built a website that’s swift and easy to access by both brand partners and clients.</p>
          <ol>
            <li>After signing up and creating an account, login into your back office the click copy <span class="fw-bold">‘default brand partners link’</span>. Share your link on <span class="fw-bold">social platforms</span> that can be visible potential clients.</li>
            <img src="" />                     
              <div>
                <ol>
                  <li>Create a target audience</li>
                  <li>Set a daily goal target that includes number of people and how much he want to make.</li>
                  <li>Set the amount of times he want to work a week.</li>
                  <li>Products and services he want to market (optional)</li>
                </ol>
              </div>
              <p>Target: 40% male, 60% female</p>
              <p>Goals: 4 people a day, ₦50,000 a day</p>
              <p>Work: 4 times a week</p>
              <p>
                <span>*lets assume Ade already did his homework by attending our webinars, where he learnt how to market like a pro and he already posted his business links on every social platform and uses his online messaging apps.
                </span>
              </p>
              <div>
                <div class="heading-color mt-5">
                  <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 1</h5>
                </div>
                <p>Ade’s target for the day is 4 people and he got 2 men and 2 women.</p>
                <p><span>MEN</span></p>
                <p>1st man did deep tissue massage and jelly pedicure</p>
                <p>2nd man never left his house, he just order online 1 ultra shade Creamy gel and 1 Lightening glow milk</p>
                <p><span>WOMEN</span></p>
                <p>1st woman did a brightening facials and braided her hair</p>
                <p>2nd woman did a botanical pedicure and botanical manicure</p>
                <div>
                  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered border-dark">
                    <tr class="th">
                      <th>MEN</th>
                      <th>PRICE</th>
                      <th>WOMEN</th>
                      <th>PRICE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Deep Tissues massage</td>
                      <td>12,000</td>
                      <td>Brightening facials</td>
                      <td>9,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Jelly Pedicure</td>
                      <td>5,000</td>
                      <td>Corn row</td>
                      <td>5,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Ultra shade creamy gel</td>
                      <td>5,000</td>
                      <td>Botanical pedicure</td>
                      <td>5,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Lightening glow milk</td>
                      <td>10,000</td>
                      <td>Botanical manicure</td>
                      <td>3,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>TOTAL</td>
                      <td>32,000</td>
                      <td>TOTAL</td>
                      <td>22,000</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
            <div class="heading-color ">
              <h5 class="total">OVERALL TOTAL =54,000</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="heading-color mt-5">
            <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 2</h5>
          </div>
          <p>Ade repeated same target as day 1.</p>
          <p>4 people but this time his message only attracted 4 women who just wanted to do the best friends package and relax themselves.</p>
          <p><span>WOMEN</span></p>
          <p>2 best-friends package comprises of 3 services each -</p>
          <p>deep cleansing facials, Swedish massage and botanical pedicure</p>
          <div>
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered border-dark">
                      <tr class="th">
                        <th>WOMEN</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Best friend package</td>
                        <td>42,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Best friend package</td>
                        <td>42,000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="heading-color">
                      <h5 class="total"  >OVERALL TOTAL =84,000</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="heading-color mt-5">
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 10px">DAY 3</h5>
                  </div>
                  <p>
                    Same target, same goal. 4 people. Repeated strategy brings
                    repeated results
                  </p>
              
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this , but once I remove the overflow-X : hidden from the root there’s a white space by the right of the code on mobile